# How to find the pairs that are relatively prime in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to put numbers in an array and take the ones that are at equal distances from the end of the interval

Example: 6 numbers, {3, 4, 6, 36, 45, 97} -> 3 and 97, 4 and 45, 6 36;

Then I need to check if they are relatively prime.

Example: 3 and 97 are relatively prime, because they have no common divisors, 4 and 45 as well, but not 6 and 36 because they have 2, 3 and 6.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, nn, nnn, v[1000], cntPairs = 0;

    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
    nn = n/2;
    nnn = ceil(n/2);

    cout << "The pairs are: \n";

    if(n % 2 == 0){
        for(int i=0; i<nn; i++){
            if(v[i] % v[n - i - 1] != 0){
                    cntPairs++;
            cout << v[i] << " " << v[n - i - 1] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if(n % 2 == 1){
        for(int i=0; i<nnn; i++){
            if(v[i] % v[n - i - 1] !=0){
                    cntPairs++;
            cout << v[i] << " " << v[n - i - 1] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "Number of pairs: " << cntPairs;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, my program does that from what I am concerned, but if I put 6 and 36 it says they are prime between themselves, which they are not, and I cant find a way to make it so it does the calculation for 36 and 6, not 6 and 36.

My only assumption is that I have to find the biggest among the 2 and put the bigger one first, but I don't know how.

Comment: The term you are looking for is called [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20two%20integers,does%20not%20divide%20the%20other.).  A typical way to solve this is to find the prime factors of each number and then make sure there is no intersection between those two sets.

Comment: `if(v[i] % v[n - i - 1] != 0)` This is incorrect. You're checking to see if one number is divisible by another, but that won't work in the instance of 8 and 12, which don't divide each other, but have shared factors.

Comment: A simple, albeit slow, approach to finding the factors would be to use a for loop starting at i=2 and increasing until your number N, then check if `N%i == 0`, and if so, add i to your array of factors, divide N by i, and start again at i=2 until the loop terminates.

Comment: @David I realized that as i was writing it, but as i said, couldn't find a better option (at the time), and the for loop you talked about did pass through my mind, but just like the way you put it, its too slow

NathanOliver thanks for telling me, if you could provide an example of such an algorithm that would be perfect

Comment: Well you can optimize it further by only testing prime numbers as factors of your number N.

Comment: You might use `std::gcd(v[i], n - i - 1) == 1`, but I would even do a function `bool are_coprime(std::size_t, std::size_t)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 is the "std::" necessary if i already have the "using namespace std"?

Comment: BTW, is seems you isolate the issue to compute correctly if `6`, `36` are coprime, so you might remove the array stuff from the question.

Comment: @MickeyMoise: I would remove `using namespace std;` instead of `std::` ;-)

Comment: i assume it's related to optimization, but i need to keep it since it's an exercise from school homework and we haven't yet been taught about std::, nor the gcd() function you wrote about, although i know it's related to Euclid's algorithm or smth like that :)

Comment: It is not about optimization, but to avoid name collision. gcd stands for greatest common divisor and indeed Euclid's algorithm allow to compute it. if you cannot use `std::gcd`, you might re-implement it. (and you have `std::gcd` to test it as comparison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two integers are relatively prime if and only if their greatest common divisor is 1. Therefore, to check whether `x` and `y` are relatively prime, do `std::gcd(x, y) == 1` (std::gcd requires C++17, GCC has __gcd, or implement it yourself).

other observations:

1. `ceil(n/2)` is equal to `n/2`. Use `(n+1)/2` if you want to round up.
2. You don't need to separately consider the cases where `n` is even and odd. This would work for all cases:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
   if (std::gcd(v[i], v[n-i-1]) == 1) {
       /* ... */
   }
}
```